# WCF Data Services + Entities with Enums

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am learning WCF Data Services (version 5.6.4). I found a very basic example.

Code for CodeFirstSampleService.svc.cs:

```
public class CodeFirstSampleService : EntityFrameworkDataService<BlogContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        AddDataToBlogContext(new BlogContext());
    }

    private static void AddDataToBlogContext(BlogContext dataSource)
    {
        var b1 = new Blog() { BlogId = 1, BlogName = "SampleBlog" };
        dataSource.Blogs.Add(b1);
        dataSource.Posts.Add(new Post()
        {
            Blog = b1,
            BlogId = b1.BlogId,
            PostId = 1,
            PostName = "Using EntityFrameworkProvider"
        });
        dataSource.SaveChanges();
    }

    [WebGet]
    public string GetFirstPostName()
    {
        var context = new BlogContext();
        return context.Posts.Select(x => x.PostName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Code for DataModel.cs

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string BlogName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string PostName { get; set; }
    //public ColorEnum Color { get; set; }
    //public PostContent Content { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

It works pretty well. If I Start debugging (in a browser):

[image]

[image]

Now let's say I also have an enum inside the Post entity.

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string PostName { get; set; }
    public ColorEnum Color { get; set; } // <---- added ENUM here
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public enum ColorEnum
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}
```

At runtime, when starting the service, I got an error: **The property 'Color' on type 'Post' is of type 'ColorEnum' which is not a supported primitive type.**

I am aware about that: enums are not supported with WCF Data Services.

Some workarounds are possible:

- for example using the `[NotMapped]` attribute on the enum property. But in my case, I cannot proceed like that because I have solution with EF Code First already in production since several years with some enums and I need it, I cannot simply ignore it with the [NotMapped] attribute on the entity.
- I tried adding `[DataMember]` and `[DataContract]` attributes but it does not work: still got the error message about enums.

  ```
  [DataContract]
  public class Post
  {
     [DataMember]
     public int PostId { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string PostName { get; set; }

     public ColorEnum Color { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public int BlogId { get; set; }
     public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
  }
  ```

What are the other alternatives ?

Please note that I have (let's say) 20 entities in my context but only need 2 of them to be used in my WCF Data Service. And furthermore only need these 2 entities to be in 'read-only' mode (no need for create, update, ...).

How can I keep my entities with enums usable for the rest of the application but prevent the enum properties from getting an error in my WCF Data Service ?

Please also note that I already searched for other SO questions on this subject but didn't found any solution allowing me to keep enums on my existing Entities.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the example form MSDN
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e844d7e1-cdf3-4631-82e0-e1a096e91d7e/wcf-enum-datacontract-serialization?forum=wcf

Where you decorate your enum class with [DataContract] attribute and then set your enumeration as

> [EnumMember]

```
[DataContract]
public class Car
{
    [DataMember]
    public string model;
    [DataMember]
    public CarConditionEnum condition;
}

[DataContract(Name = "CarCondition")]
public enum CarConditionEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    New,
    [EnumMember]
    Used,
    [EnumMember]
    Rental,
    Broken,
    Stolen
}
```

Comment: Yes I already tried to decorate each values of my enumeration with `[EnumMember]`  but it does not work. It seems that all these attributes `[DataContract] ... [DataMember] ... [EnumMember]` does not work with WCF Data Services. Hope someone can confirm that or explain what's the trick here.